# C# - Ternary inside anonymous object

Tags: c#, ternary

Below is a an anonymous object, assuming that `Course` object can have no related `Progress` object, so to avoid having `Progress` return an empty array, I am trying to make it return an object with values equal to zeroes:

```
var courses = await _context.courses
    .Include(c => c.Progress)
    .ToListAsync();

var myCourses = courses
    .Select(c => new
    {
        Title = c.Title,
        Progress = (c.Progress.ToList().Select(x => new { x.CurrentChapter, x.Completed }) != null)
            ? (c.Progress.ToList().Select(x => new { x.CurrentChapter, x.Completed }))
            : (new List<Dictionary<string, int>> { { "CurrentChapter", 0 }, { "Completed", 0 } })
    })
    .ToList();
    
return Ok(myCourses);
```

But I am getting an error in the last part of the ternary as follows:

> No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments

Comment: What is the type of `Progress`? Also it seems that you have some problems with generic parameters - closing `>` for `List` is positioned way to late.

Comment: The first step is not to use ternary when its not needed. If you can't understand what you're doing. Then just use if else.

Comment: The problem is the object initialization you are using, it should be something like: `var list = new List<Dictionary<string, int>> { new() { { "CurrentChapter", 0 } }, new() { { "CurrentChapter", 0 } } };` . This is because `{"Curent",0}` is not converted to a dictionary

Comment: TL;DR; You are missing the `new Dictionary`

Comment: I was going to write an answer but I got more confused the more I looked at your code. My only advice is that try avoiding huge ternary statements and use a simple if-else.

Comment: it does if you are using C# 9 =)

Comment: @taquion yep, just thought about it myself)

Comment: do you guys also realize `Select(...) != null` will never be false before correcting the syntax?

Comment: The late '>' was just a typo while copy/paste, I updated the question

Comment: @SelmanGenç yep it does not make much sense =)

Comment: You should really rewrite your code to be readable. Doing it all in one line doesn't make it faster or smaller. Why do you start with `course.Progress.ToList().Select`? I'm assuming `Progress` implements `IEnumerable<Something>`, why copy it to a list before you start? I'm pretty sure that `List<T>.Select` can't return null, so your null test does nothing. I might see more if you had made it readable

Comment: @Flydog57 course.Progress.ToList().Select return two values when Progress object exists in Course, otherwise it returns empty array, and I would like to replace the empty array with zeroes as values. I am doing all in one line because Progress is a property in an anonymous object and I would like to test the condition without having to write extra code outside the object.

Comment: Assuming `course.Progress` is enumerable, the `course.Progress.ToList()` will copy that enumerable into a new `List<T>`. Then when you call `Select`, you will create an un-materialized enumerable that contains the projection you specified. With or without the `ToList` call, you should get the same thing. Make your code readable and I'll go further

Comment: @Flydog57 Edited the question, the first part of the ternary works fine, the issue is only in the last part of the condition, when Progress returns an empty array.

Comment: @taquion Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<anonymous type: int CurrentChapter, int Completed>>' and 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>>'

Answer (score 1):

Your code as you show it is not very salvageable (nor is it anywhere near readable).  I took your code, removed the superfluous `ToList` calls and added a bit more to get it to nearly compile:

*As I mentioned in the comments, the `ToList` calls are superfluous - `course.Progress` must be enumerable, all `ToList` does is create a new list that copies the information in `course.Progress`*

My added code:

```
var course = new {Progress = new List<Progress>() };
```

That allows the `course.Progress.Select` call to make a little sense.  If `course` isn't an instance of a type that has a property named `Progress` that implements `IEnumerable<Progress`, well, I'm not sure how to start this.

Then, the beginning of your code, reformatted starts making sense (it trails off at the end).

Here's your code, without `.ToList` and reformatted:

```
var progress = (course.Progress
    .Select(x => new { x.CurrentChapter, x.Completed }) != null)
    ? (course.Progress.Select(x => new { x.CurrentChapter, x.Completed })) 
    : (new List<Dictionary<string, int>{ { "CurrentChapter", 0 }, { "Completed", 0 } });
```

As I mentioned in the comments, `IEnumerable<T>.Select` never returns `null`, so the initial null check is useless.  I'm guessing that you are trying to check that the progress collection is empty.

Also note that when you use a ternary, both possible choices must be the same type.  In one case, you have an anonymous type, in the other, you have a Dictionary.  That's never going to compile.

Like the other commenters, I think you are better off  using an `if/else`.  However, since you seem to want to get get an anonymously typed thing called `Progress`.  I don't have a clue how you declared that, so I worked around it with a tuple.  I think this is kinda-sorta what you are trying to do:

```
(int currentChapter, int completed) progressTuple;
if(!course.Progress.Any())
{
    progressTuple = (0, 0);
}
else
{
    var firstProgress = course.Progress.First();
    progressTuple = (firstProgress.CurrentChapter, firstProgress.Completed);
}
var progress = new { CurrentChapter = progressTuple.currentChapter, Completed = progressTuple.completed };
```

Now, `progress` is an anonymous type like you seem to want.  Note that I picked the first item out of your collection.  I don't really know what you wanted to do there.

Since you have a type named `Progress` that has the properties you wanted, this would make more sense:

```
Progress progress;
if (!course.Progress.Any())
{
    progress = new Progress { CurrentChapter = 0, Completed = 0 };
}
else
{
    progress  = course.Progress.First();
}
```

Now that you have code that is simplified and that makes sense, you could try reintroducing a ternary operator if your tastes run towards the unreadable (I find complex ternaries at the edge of my code comprehension skills).

Comment: Your ultimate part makes sense, I just need to specify the two properties and try to reintroduce the ternary because I can't see how I can put a condition in an anonymous object property.

Comment: converted to ternary it looks like: Progress = (!course.Progress.Any()) ? (course.Progress.First()) : (new Progress { CurrentChapter = 0, Completed = 0 }) and it doesn't give error, but it always return 0 in values even if Progress can be not empty.

Comment: Is that what you wanted? Don't forget the upvote and/or accept buttons

Comment: It is still not what is required, it returns 0 in the values regardless if Progress is an empty array or not, and Progress with your ultimate code is just an object, not an array of objects (when it is not empty of course), I think it is needed to keep the .ToList()

Comment: Well, you are going to need to define what the type of `course.Progress` is, show an idea of what is in it, and what you really want your output to look like.   You should also specify what you meant by that null check.  There's a limit to my mind-reading skills. Thanks for adding a bunch more code, but the code you added doesn't really clarify things (in fact, it obfuscates it somewhat).  BTW, you don't need the `.ToList` before the `OrderBy` either.  As I mentioned, you will _never_ get a ternary to work if you have incompatible types for the two choices (think about it)

Answer (score 0):

Discussion with @Flydog57 helped me dissipate some confusion since this is the first time I make a ternary inside an anonymous object, and after made some edits to my question to make it short and concise, and [some research](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-conditional-expression), I could finally solve the issue, here is what I ended up to:

```
var myCourses = courses
    .Select(c => new
    {
        Title = c.Title,
        Progress = (c.Progress.Any())
                    ? (c.Progress.ToList().Select(x => new { x.CurrentChapter, x.Completed }))
                    : (new[] { new {CurrentChapter = 0, Completed = 0} }.ToList())
    })
    .ToList();
```

So using Dictionary in the last part was not the correct way, and also the first part was not relevant, so now instead of returning:

```
{
    "title": "Course having child Progress objects",
    "progress": [
        {
            "currentChapter": 2,
            "completed": 0
        },
        {
            "currentChapter": 0,
            "completed": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "title": "Course having NO child Progress objects",
    "progress": []
}
```

it is returning:

```
{
    "title": "Course having child Progress objects",
    "progress": [
        {
            "currentChapter": 2,
            "completed": 0
        },
        {
            "currentChapter": 0,
            "completed": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "title": "Course having NO child Progress objects",
    "progress": [
        {
            "currentChapter": 0,
            "completed": 0
        }
    ]
}
```